# Fuerte turtlebot simulator Ubuntu 12.04 precise

Tags: simulation, turtlebot, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am having a hard time running the turtlebot simulator with ros-fuerte on Ubuntu precise 12.04. I used to run the simulator without any problems with Ubuntu Lucid and ros-electric. It seems to be an issue with the gazebo server and the boost libraries. More specifically, after issuing:

> roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
> I get the following error:
> --
> waiting for service spawn_urdf_model
> gzserver: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: T* boost::shared_ptr::operator->() const [with T = urdf::Inertial]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.

> Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details

> Aborted (core dumped)

I have observed the same behavior on 3 different 12.04 machines (Ububtu, lubuntu, Xubuntu). Is this a known problem for fuerte-precise turtlebot simulator or am I doing sth wrong? Note that stripping down the turtlebot urdf to just the create base seems to  work - but that's definitely not a solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38465/fuerte-turtlebot-simulator-ubuntu-12.04-precise/) by [Savvas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2809/savvas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-07-10

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that in the turtlebot_description/urdf/turtlebot_body.urdf.xacro file they had commented out this:

```
<inertial>
  <mass value="0.0001" />
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
  <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0"
          iyy="0.0001" iyz="0.0" 
          izz="0.0001" />
</inertial>
```

After removing the commented out part, the turtlebot was spawned correctly and all of the topics seem to be published as well.

The only issue is that while running you will be bombarded by this warning:

Warning [RaySensor.cc:206] ranges not constructed yet (zero sized)

But other than that it seems to run correctly.

---

Originally posted by [mgrimson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2829/mgrimson/) with karma: 36 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Savvas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2809/savvas/) on 2012-07-12**:
Thank you very much for this. Indeed this fixed the problem.

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2012-07-24**:
This seems to be a more general problem. I guess, this part was commented out, because otherwise KDL complains about not being able to handle inertia in the first link. Leaving the inertia out was working for Electric, but now it crashes with the new Gazebo.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this has been addressed in trunk of simulator_gazebo (see [r29773](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/changeset/39773/stacks/simulator_gazebo/trunk)), with release of simulator_gazebo 1.6.12, the inertial block is not needed any more.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on 2012-08-03**:
Any idea on when this will be out, or is there anywhere were I can check when it will be out? Thanks.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-04**:
just made a release, see http://www.ros.org/debbuild/fuerte.html for deb build status of simulator_gazebo 1.6.12.

**Comment by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on 2012-08-08**:
Now it no longer yields the problem above, but it still fails. I will post a comment below with the details.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Updating with "simulator_gazebo 1.6.12" no longer gives the problem mentioned above due to inertial information missing, but it still crashes with the following:

```
hcostelha@orange:p2os> roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch
... logging to /home/hcostelha/.ros/log/2718b24c-e0a3-11e1-a2a1-0022695aa7fd/roslaunch-orange-3108.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is  ignored
process[master]: started with pid [3128]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 2718b24c-e0a3-11e1-a2a1-0022695aa7fd
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3141]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [3155]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [3159]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-4]: started with pid [3166]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[diagnostic_aggregator-5]: started with pid [3167]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[robot_state_publisher-6]: started with pid [3168]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[robot_pose_ekf-7]: started with pid [3184]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[pointcloud_throttle-8]: started with pid [3220]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[kinect_laser-9]: started with pid [3235]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[kinect_laser_narrow-10]: started with pid [3250]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

loading model xml from ros parameter
waiting for service spawn_urdf_model
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1344352728.268076752]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 3155, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo -u /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/turtlebot_simulator/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/hcostelha/.ros/log/2718b24c-e0a3-11e1-a2a1-0022695aa7fd/gazebo-2.log].                                                          
log file: /home/hcostelha/.ros/log/2718b24c-e0a3-11e1-a2a1-0022695aa7fd/gazebo-2*.log                                                                                              
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui: line 2:  3165 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) `rospack find gazebo`/gazebo/bin/gzclient -g `rospack find gazebo`/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 3159, exit code 132, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gui __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/hcostelha/.ros/log/2718b24c-e0a3-11e1-a2a1-0022695aa7fd/gazebo_gui-3.log].                                                                                                                                   
log file: /home/hcostelha/.ros/log/2718b24c-e0a3-11e1-a2a1-0022695aa7fd/gazebo_gui-3*.log                                                                                          
^C[kinect_laser_narrow-10] killing on exit
[kinect_laser-9] killing on exit
[pointcloud_throttle-8] killing on exit
[robot_pose_ekf-7] killing on exit
 [robot_state_publisher-6] killing on exit
[diagnostic_aggregator-5] killing on exit
[spawn_turtlebot_model-4] killing on exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/spawn_model", line 277, in 
    sm.callSpawnService()
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/spawn_model", line 262, in callSpawnService
    rospy.wait_for_service('/gazebo/unpause_physics')
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 158, in wait_for_service
    raise ROSInterruptException("rospy shutdown")
rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException: rospy shutdown
[rosout-1] killing on exit
[master] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done
```

The *gazebo-2.log never gets to be created, and *gazebo_gui-3*.log just says "Waiting for master", so they are not of much help.

Any ideas?

---

Originally posted by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) with karma: 230 on 2012-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on 2012-08-08**:
Yep, ran an upgrade tonight and there was a bunch of Fuerte updates.  I get this error intermittently and it stops Gazebo loading. If I try a second time Gazebo appears to load....

**Comment by [hcostelha](https://answers.ros.org/users/839/hcostelha/) on 2012-08-18**:
I tried today after another batch of updates and it is working now. The simulator_gazebo is still version 1.6.12, so It the problem now might have been elsewhere.